# Updating EXTJS 4 Treepanel periodic

Tags: extjs, refresh, treepanel, extjs4

I would like to create a `Treepanel`, which is updated once a second.
So I took a store with a proxy for data acquistion:

```
store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
    model: 'TaskState',
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : '/getTaskList'
},
    root: {
        expanded: true
}});
```

The store seems to work, the data is displayed in my `TreePanel`.

I tried to update the `Treepanel` with this function:

```
function refresh(){
        store.load();
        window.setTimeout("refresh()", 1000);
    }
```

The update seems to work as well. Unfortunately the update causes some kind of "blinking" effekt on every update, because the whole tree is reloaded. I'm searching for a way to only refresh the nodes, which have changed.

Is there some way to do this?

greetings

Answer (score 2):

There is one way:
You can load your nodes to some temp store and change your main tree's store node by node

Comment: Hmm, can you post a small example please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add any new node and do not want to reload the whole store then you can add like this

```
 //overModel is Ext.data.Model
 overModel.appendChild({
                        id: responseJson.data['id'],
                        text:responseJson.data['text'],
                        children:responseJson.data['children'],//array of childern
                        parent_id:responseJson.data['parent_id']

  });
  overModel.expand();
```

and if you want to load the whole store the you can do something like this

`Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('StoreName').load({ params: {"p1": p1}});`

to load the store. 
To update the store periodically you can use [DelatedTask](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask) Class.

check out the [Documentation API](http://docs.sencha.com) of EXTJS will give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

Store is bind  Treepanel like grid and store ,so you can get  Store from tree panel with

```
var store=treepanel.getStore()
```

and you can reload the store with branch that you need update with

```
store.load({node:selectedNode})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TaskManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner) for that:

```
Ext.TaskManager.start({
    run: reloadStoreFunction,
    interval: 1000
});
```

This would execute reloadStoreFunction every second.